# Одна разметка для разных экранов

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

У сайта есть несколько брейкпоинтов (1280, 760 и т.д.). На hd устройствах, все работает, как ожидается. Но на других, у которых макс ширина, например 1024, сайт показывается, как для ширины 760+. Как можно указать брейкпоинты, в зависимости от реальной ширины устройства, что для экранов 1024 и для экранов 1280 и больше вид был одинаковый? (Использую react + material ui)

Answer (score 0):

Просто используйте те брейкпоинты, которые вам реально нужны. Также можете комбинировать условия `min-width` и `max-width`, чтобы получить нужные промежутки.
Пример:

```
/* <= 760px */
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) { ... }

/* 760 < X <= 1280 */
@media screen and (min-width: 761px) and (max-width: 1280px) { ... }

/* > 1280 */
@media screen and (max-width: 1281px) { ... }
```

Comment: Наверное, я не правильно донес вопрос. Нужно, чтобы на устройствах с макс шириной 1024px сайт отображался, как будто макс ширина 1280px

Comment: возможно нужно использовать % отношение (получать в js) и уже его использовать в качестве брейкпоинта

Comment: Насколько понимаю, у вас `@media` прописаны через `min-width`, поэтому на экране 1024px отображается как на 760px. Замените на `@media (max-width: )` и тогда на экране 600px будет отображаться как на 760px, а на экране 1024px - как на 1280px